# make table row clickable + Hover change background

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, hover

I have a MVC application and I want to make my table row clickable and then when I hover over it, I want to  change the background of it.

I have the following code that I got from a blog

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#example tbody tr').click(function () {
          alert('row was clicked');
      });
  });     

</script>
```

I wanted to add the hover capability, so I modified it to:

```
$<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#example tbody tr').click(function () {
             alert('row was clicked');
         });
    });

   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example tbody tr').hover(function () {
            $(this).css('background-color','#ccc');
        }, function () {
            $(this).css('background-color','#fff');
   });
</script>
```

my HTML:

```
<table id="example" border = "2">
    <thead>
    <tr style="border-style:solid"  class="simplehighlight">
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>
        <th>
            tblStatu
        </th>
        <th>
            DueDate
        </th>
        <th>
            AssignedTo
        </th>
        <th>
            CreatedOn
        </th>
        <th>
            CreatedBy
        </th>
        <th>
            ModifiedOn
        </th>
        <th>
            ModifiedBy
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr style="border-style:solid">
        <td style="border-style:solid">
            @item.Name

            @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)*@
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tblStatu.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DueDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AssignedTo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedOn)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedBy)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ModifiedOn)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ModifiedBy)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.TaskId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.TaskId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.TaskId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
   </tbody>
```

The click handler works, but the hover over function doesn't.  What could be the problem?

Comment: (1) Please post the actual rendered HTML, not the server-side code. (2) What does "just does not seem to work" mean? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Your selector is wrong: it matches rows inside a `<tbody>` element, but your rows are inside a `<thead>`.

Comment: Frederic is right. change `$('#example tbody tr')` to `$('#example tr')`. And for the hover part, i recommend using css.

Comment: HI Guys, I am sorry I should had been more specific. The code abpove works( which is just click() code) but as soon as I add Hover login in it does not work.After adding Hover logic my code looks like somthing below

Comment: `$<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#example tbody tr').click(function () {
          alert('row was clicked');
      });
  });

   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example tbody tr').hover(function () {
            $(this).css('background-color','#ccc');
        }, function () {
            $(this).css('background-color','#fff');
        });

</script>`

Comment: @Californicated - edit your question to add updates, don't put them as comments.

Comment: @Frédéric The selector is not wrong.  The `tbody` element starts right before the `foreach`.  The `foreach` adds additional rows.

Comment: Hi Guys, I am sorry for the bad formatting I just tried to press enter and it posted the whole comment. I am truly sorry for that.

Comment: Please remember Click() part works until and unless I add the second Hover() part

Comment: @tvanfosson, you're right, I missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After adding the code from your comment into the question, I noticed that you're missing a closing `});` on your second document ready handler.  Try the following.  Notice I'm using one ready handler and chaining the jQuery functions to the same selector -- part of the beauty of jQuery.

```
$<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example tbody tr').click(function () {
             alert('row was clicked');
        }).hover(function () {
              $(this).css('background-color','#ccc');
           }, function () {
              $(this).css('background-color','#fff');
        });
    });
</script>
```

As @Chris Pietschmann notes, though, you could get the same effect with CSS which gives you less code to maintain.

```
<style>
#example tbody tr:hover
{
    background-color: #ccc;
}
</style>
```

Comment: It would have been really easy to find this just by looking at any browser's error console.

Comment: @Dennis No disagreement here.  It was somewhat challenging here as the original question didn't include the non-working code. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to define a different background color on hover:

```
tr:hover
{
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: That would apply to the rows in the header, too.  Not what seems to be desired.  It would also apply to all tables so if he only wants it for one table, he'd have to use a much more specific selector.

Comment: @tvanfosson or just a class on the table `table.hoverable tr:hover {...}`